# How to install chrome-webdriver on GitLab CI/CD

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, robotframework

I am trying to do some tests using GitLab CI/CD and Robot Framework, I have this simple `.robot` file:

```
*** Settings ***
# Declare Libraries
Library  SeleniumLibrary

# Declare Suite Setup and Teardown
Suite Setup Open Browser    ${site_to_open}  ${browser_to_use}
Suite Teardown  Close Browser

*** Variables ***
${site_to_open}  https://example.com/
${browser_to_use}   chrome

*** Test Cases ***

Open webpage and check for text
    Page Should Contain  Check for existence of this text!!!
    Log  OK
```

In my .gitlab-ci.yml I have this

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy
  - tests1

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp test_website/index.html .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master

tests1:
  stage: tests1
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome
  script:
  - python3 -V
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y python3-pip
  - pip3 -V
  - pip3 install robotframework
  - pip3 install robotframework-seleniumlibrary
  - apt-get install -y chromium-chromedriver
  - export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
  - robot --output NONE --report NONE --log NONE cases/Test/test.robot
  only:
  - master
```

However when I try to run the pipeline it gives me this error:

```
$ apt-get install -y chromium-chromedriver
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package chromium-chromedriver
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Whatever I am doing, I am failing to sucessfully instal the chromium-webdriver to run the Robot Framework test as in headless Chrome.

Could you suggest how to edit the files to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by this yaml:

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy
  - tests1

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp test_website/index.html .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master

tests1:
  stage: tests1
  script:
  # Update apt-get and install pip
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y python3-pip
  # Install robot framework and the selenium library
  - pip3 install robotframework
  - pip3 install robotframework-seleniumlibrary
  # Install the chrome and chrome webdriver
  - apt-get install -y xvfb
  - apt-get install -y zip
  - apt-get install -y wget
  - apt-get install -y ca-certificates
  - apt-get install -y libnss3-dev libasound2 libxss1 libappindicator3-1 libindicator7 gconf-service libgconf-2-4 libpango1.0-0 xdg-utils fonts-liberation libgbm1
  - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
  - dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb 
  - rm google-chrome*.deb
  - wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/89.0.4389.23/chromedriver_linux64.zip
  - unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
  - chmod +x chromedriver
  - cp chromedriver /usr/local/bin
  - rm chromedriver_linux64.zip
  - rm chromedriver
  # Run the test case
  - robot --output NONE --report NONE --log NONE cases/Test/test.robot
  only:
  - master
```